# Can only open bukkit.sh with Java Web Start

Tags: command-line, permissions, executable

I'm trying to run bukkit.sh file with java 7 runtime. Instead the only application I can associate the bukkit.sh java file is java web start.

I've done the basics, installed java7, set the bukkit.sh file to be executable.

Answer (score 0):

Appart of don't understanding why the file has `sh` as the extension being a java executable and all, I see just one way to do this. Using the shebang.

Edit your file and add the following line at the start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env java
....
```

This shebang tells the interpreter to execute the file using the binary called `java`.